# Speed Limit Value of the Road from the OSM

Tags: php, server, openstreetmap, latitude-longitude

I am trying to get the maximum speed limit value of the road from the OSM server after sending the latitude and longitude co-ordinates. I have completed the code, but there seems to be a problem in loading them. I do not understand what is the problem. Below given is the php code:

```
<?php

//$lat  = isset($_GET['lat']) ? floatval($_GET['lat']) :  "";
//$lng = isset($_GET['lng']) ? floatval($_GET['lng']) :  "";

$lat  = 24.192163;
$lng = 55.649185;

$latm = -0.00015 + $lat;
//$latm = 24.229544;                    //s
echo $latm. "\n";

$lngm = -0.00015 + $lng;
//$lngm = 55.775513;                    //w
echo $lngm. "\n";

$latp = 0.00015 + $lat;
//$latp = 24.229844;                    //n
echo $latp. "\n";

$lngp = 0.00015 + $lng;
//$lngp = 55.775813;                    //e
echo $lngp;

$json_url = 'http://overpass.osm.rambler.ru/cgi/interpreter';

$data = '<query type="way"> <bbox-query s="' . $latm . '" w="' . $lngm . '" n="' . $latp . '" e="' . $lngp . '"/> <!--this is auto-completed with the current map view coordinates.--> </query> <print/>';

$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

$options = array(
CURLOPT_POST => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'),
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result =  curl_exec($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

foreach ($xml->way as $i) {
    foreach ($i->tag as $tag) {
        if ($tag['k'] == "maxspeed") {
            $maxspeed = $tag['v'];
            break;
        }
    }
}

$response["speedlimit"] = "$maxspeed";
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

For testing purposes, I have already set $lat and $lng co-ordinates of certain area to get the speed limit. But, it doesn't work.

I hope someone can guide me to the right direction. Thanks alot...

Comment: So, what output do you get?

Comment: "doesn't work" is a bit too vague to help. What is the error message do you get? where do you get stuck at?

Comment: Actually, nothing! The page just loads and takes lot of time and then the page dies saying 'no respone'. :(

Comment: try adding `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of your script to disable PHP script timeout.

Comment: its still the same.. no change!

Comment: Can you show us an example URL that you are trying to load? Does it work when loading this URL in your browser?

Comment: This code seems to be working just fine. Does it happen the first time you try it, or is it after heavy load? Do you see anything in your PHP's error log?

Comment: The code works and returns `24.192013 55.649035 24.192313 55.649335{"speedlimit":"80"}` on the browser.  Maybe it is a problem with your curl setup or network (are you behind a proxy?) rather than the php code itself.